# Where to call animation in custom view on display

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I created a custom view which should have an animation the moment it is visible to the user (it is rotating endlessly).

I put this in the `awakeFromNib` function but I am not sure if this is the right place because there are times (unfortunately not regularly) when the animation does not start.

Code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    // property changes here
  }
}
```

Is that the right place or is there a better function I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to create a func such as startAnimation inside the custom class  and do

```
customView.startAnimation()
```

in `viewDidAppear` of the VC you add it to , to be sure that the customView and it's parent view are completely laid out

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, makes sense for me. Still feels weird that I always need to call it when using this view, even though this animation should always start. Will give you the check mark if no other answer flies in :)

Comment: Went with this approach. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`awakeFromNib` is a good place. A better way to go about this is to start animating after your custom view has been added as a subview to a view, like this:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        // Your animation
    }
}
```

So whenever you call `addSubview`, the animation will start playing.

---

**Note:**

> Subclasses can override `didMoveToSuperview` to perform additional actions whenever the
>   superview changes.

If you move your custom view to any other index of `subviews` (via for ex., `bringSubviewToFront`), its superview will change, so this method will get called again *(because the superview changes).*

Comment: Sound very good, will try it out, thanks. Esp. when working with storyboards.

Comment: This approach also worked but I thought the other was more elegant. It also had the nice side effect that the dev could decide whether or not to start the animation.